# Copy file to same path as source without changing directories

Tags: bash, cp

Suppose I have a path like this under some directory (e.g. home): `~/mydir/subdir/file1`,and I want to make a copy of *file1*:

We could do this from the home directory:

```
cp ~/mydir/subdir/file1 ~/mydir/subdir/file2
```

Is there a shortcut that means "in the same path as the source" so I don't have to repeat the `mydir/subdir` portion again, just like `.` means the current directory? Or another way to achieve the same result?

I know I can `cd ~/mydir/subdir` first, but I'm looking for a one line solution that would allow me to stay in the same directory. One option would be to use a variable, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way when typing lots of commands.

Had a look at `man cp` and searched online but couldn't find such an option. If the answer is a definite "no" that's fine too, just thought I'd check if there's a time saving trick others use. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using `bash` (1), and assuming path without space or new line (2), I would use

```
cp ~/mydir/subdir1/{file1,file2}
```

this would be expanded by bash to (along with `~` expansion)

```
cp ~/mydir/subdir1/file1 ~/mydir/subdir1/file2
```

as always you can test using `echo`

```
echo cp ~/mydir/subdir1/{file1,file2}
```

---

As per comment :

(1) this may work on other shell, I didn't have time to test them all.

(2) for "funny" names, either use <kbd>tab</kbd> completion (so `bash` will put proper escape), or use quotes (but not arround braces) :

```
mv ./"some dir"/{"some name","other id"}
```

Comment: Note that that syntax is from csh in the late 70s, it's not specific to bash and is supported by most shells nowadays.

Comment: There is no issue with spaces or newlines as word splitting happens after brace expansion.

Comment: just need to quote the insides of the brace expansion (but not the braces). something like `mv ./"some dir"/{"some name","other id"}` should work

Comment: “as always you can test using `echo`”, thanks, I didn't that existed and it's awesome!

Answer (score 7):

With a subshell `( ... )` one can `chdir` into the desired directory and if that `chdir` did not fail perform the copy. The `chdir` only influences the working directory of the subshell, not of the parent shell process.

```
( cd ~/mydir/subdir && cp file1 file2 )
```

This could be abstracted into a shell function without too much difficulty, and tab completion would not be very hard to make relative to the offset working directory (at least for ZSH).

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Don't know how to make tab completion work for `cp` though... using bash.

Comment: With GNU `env`, see also `env -C ~/mydir/subdir cp file1 file2`

Answer (score 5):

Using `find` with `-execdir` (where supported, initially from BSD, but also supported by GNU `find`)

> but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file

For example

```
find ~/mydir/subdir/file1 -prune -execdir cp "{}" file2 \;
```

(`-prune` to make sure that if ever `file1` is of type *directory*, `find` doesn't end up copying every file within to `file2`; `cp` would complain in any case if asked to copy a directory without `-r` / `-a`).

Answer (score 3):

**Interactively**, there's an `icp` command like `imv`, that gives you a readline editing environment with the filename.  It's in the "renameutils" package.  See the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/imv.1.html)

```
...$ icp   ~/foo/bar/baz
> /home/user/foo/bar/baz       # edit this and hit return.  it runs cp for you
```

Tab completion is available while editing, at least if the path doesn't contain spaces.  It seems to fail with those, unfortunately.

They prompt before overwriting the destination file if it exists.

`icp` and `imv` have some default options they pass to `cp` or `mv` respectively, including `cp`'s `--no-preserve` (of attributes like timestamps).

---

Or, **line-editing features make it very easy and fast to duplicate the path without *typing* it again.**

- Start by typing `cp ~/mydir/subdir/`  (*tab completion is available*)
- If the path contains no spaces, a single ctrl-w will "kill" it, storing it in the kill ring.  If there are spaces, it'll take more than 1, and if you overshoot and kill the `cp` as well, it'll be part of the kill-ring entry even if you use ctrl-/ to undo the overshoot.

  Or ctrl-a, ctrl-right-arrow to place the cursor after the `cp`, then ctrl-k to kill-to-end-of-line.
- Yank back what you killed with ctrl-y, so your command line is back to step 1, but with the directory ready to paste
- type the source filename (*tab completion is available*)
- Hit space, then **yank another copy of the path with ctrl-y**.  Now your command line looks like
  `cp ~/mydir/subdir/file1 ~/mydir/subdir/`
- Type the final filename  (*tab completion is available*)

The same building blocks can be used in other orders.   For example if you started typing or copy/pasting the source path including filename, and only after that you realize you want the copy to be in that directory, ctrl-left-arrow to move the cursor backward-word before killing/yanking the directory part, then ctrl-e for end of line before yanking another copy of it.

Or if you want to **give the copy a similar filename**, kill / 2x yank the whole path including filename, then edit the 2nd copy (destination). Again, tab-completion is available at all stages.

If you accidentally kill something else so ctrl-y yanks the wrong thing, alt-y to cycle back through previous kill-ring entries.

These interactive line-editing tools are extremely useful all the time, not just for `cp`.  Cursor-movement by "word", and kill forward/backward word, are highly useful for quickly editing and copying paths.